# Does thrift support batching of api calls?

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, web-services, thrift

I have a service that exposes certain functionality using thrift apis. But in order to minimize the latency between my client and service, is there any support for batching multiple api calls? what are some of the recommendations?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

In short, no. However, if latency is a significant concern, you could define a "compound" call that is composed of multiple requests.

In this scenario, an individual request would contain all your possible requests as optional members while containing a required field that specifies the particular kind of request actually contained (essentially a union). The compound request would, in turn, be composed of a list of such individual requests.